# How to configure Ctrl+backspace Linux behavior in macOS terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, shortcut

I was using Windows and Ubuntu previously and in their terminal, when I used to press `Ctrl + Backspace` it used to delete the last word till any punctuation. For example, if I had typed:

`ls -l /usr/local/foo`

on the terminal and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, then the result would be `ls -l /usr/local/`.

I am very new to the Mac world and searched a lot of places but I could not find this behaviour. I did find that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> deletes the entire word till whitespace and the result would be `ls -l`.

I would like to keep this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> behaviour as well as get back the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> behaviour that I had on Windows and Ubuntu.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: This is no OS feature, but one of the shell you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this to work the way you want, you have to set the <kbd>option</kbd> key to be used as a Meta key. To do this:

1. Launch Terminal
2. Go to **Terminal > Preferences...**
3. Select the **Profiles** icon at top
4. Select the profile you're using from the lefthand side
5. Click on the **Keyboard** tab on the righthand side
6. Now tick the *Use Option as Meta key* checkbox at bottom of the screen
7. Exit preferences

Now to achieve what you want, do as follows:

Press <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> to delete back one word

Comment: Just a note - if you have a regular (PC, I guess) keyboard connected, it's `Alt` + `Backspace`. `Alt` + `Delete` produces an opening parentheses. Anyway, could you explain what that setting exactly does and if it has any other effects, please?